# Opening notepad file in web browser

Tags: c#

Just wondering how I can open a text file in IE through a C# command? I can only so far make the file open, and then it asks to confirm which program to open it with. This seems a bit unprofessional and that is using this code:

```
Help.ShowHelp( button5,"file:E:/Gradecalculator/Gradecalculator/index.html");
```

or this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("file:E:/Gradecalculator/Gradecalculator/index.html");
```

My issue with these is that it asks the user to select a program to open it with, and I want it to automatically open it in IE (the user WILL have IE). Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E:\Gradecalculator\Gradecalculator\index.html");` and if the user is asked to choose a program, then they need to fix their machine

Comment: Start iexplore.exe then, and pass the file as an argument, rather than rely on the shell open verb...

Comment: @RemusRusanu Ooh no. That's the opposite way around.

Comment: Are you writing this as a desktop app or a webapp?

Comment: @Jamiec I'm writing this as a desktop app, this is just a little help button because we need to include a function that opens a webpage.

Comment: So why do you need to force IE? If my default browser is, say Firefox, I want html to open in my preference (its my damn PC!!) not the developers preference.

Comment: Does it have to be internet explorer? You are seeing this box pop up because no applications are associated with your `*.html` files. Does `*.htm` make a difference? Executing a `*.htm` should open the _default_ browser. Forcing IE to open is rude imo.

Comment: my head hurts... why are you opening a text document in a web browser from a desktop application? Why not just open the text doc in the application? What is the need for the web browser?

Comment: @Jamiec Or could you please show me how to force it to open in the users default browser? Which I know is IE because as stated in the question it is homework.

Comment: @LucasHolmes - see the answer by David Heffernan. In fact you already have the right code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** Files will be opened with their associated `application` by default, if no `application` is associated by default then it will ask for user to choose the application.

**Solution :** You need to  `Associate` an `Application` with which you want to open your `file`.

Try This:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process process=new Process();
ProcessStartInfo start=new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName="IEXPLORE.exe";
start.Arguments=@"E:/Gradecalculator/Gradecalculator/index.html";
process.StartInfo=start;
process.Start();
```

Comment: you need to include `   using System.diagnostics;` in your program, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

The native answer to your direct question, is to execute `iexplore.exe` passing the URL as an argument. However, I will not recommend that, and so won't show you code. If you feel compelled to do that you can surely work out how to.

This code from your question:

```
Process.Start(@"E:\Gradecalculator\Gradecalculator\index.html");
```

is in fact the right way to do this. You should not force the user to use a specific web browser. You should respect their choice.

If this code leads to the user being asked which program to open the file with, then the issue is purely environmental. The file associations are broken on that machine.

So the right solution is to use the code above, and fix the associations.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the file associates ARE broken on my college machines, there is no default web browser, and until you set one in the session, it will ask the user to open the file from a list of programs. I want to bypass this, and I know the program will be used on a college computer as my teacher checks it.